# jquery update from 1.11.0

Tags: jquery

Please forgive the length of this post as I want to provide some background on the issue.  I have been tasked to update jQuery on an essentially "orphaned" company php website.  The site is running jQuery 1.11.0 and was developed by a consulting company over a decade ago, and they are no longer in business.  There is no local or online test environment and the host (network solutions) does not appear to have an interface, as some hosts do, to upgrade jQuery.

Since I have not done a jQuery update before I started researching (stackoverflow, jquery.com, etc..) and now feel I have a process to do this update:

1. Use the jQuery migration tool 1.4.1 to update jQuery from 1.11.0 to 3.0.
2. Use the jQuery migration tool 3.3.0 to update jQuery from 3.0 to 3.7.1.

I found that the original developer added the jQuery script(s) to the php footer, as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") { 
            document.write('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.1.11.0.min.js"></sc' + 'ript>');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.ajaxForm.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/localstorage.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure what tool the original developer used to create this php site, but I decided to use Netbeans to get a look at the code and make any needed changes. After creating a new Netbeans Project for this site, I noticed that it has a js folder containing the following:

[image]

The first script src is "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", the additional scripts are pointed to the project's js folder for boostrap.min.js, bootstrap.datepicker.js, etc...

The js folder also contains a jquery.1.11.0.min.js file - see attached image.  With that, my newbie questions are:

1. What happens to this "local" js folder's jquery.1.11.0.min.js file after I run the jquery migrations on the "live" site?  Does the migration automatically update the files in the js folder, or do I need to copy them in manually?
2. I'm planning to bring jQuery to 3.7.1, updating version by version as I've learned you can't leapfrog to the latest in one step.  If I see the site is "broken" by any of the version updates, I'll need to revert to the previous version.  Or make necessary code changes to get it working with the latest jQuery version. Is this process the method you would follow, or are there other considerations you can share?

I appreciate your help for a jQuery newbie :)

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP when the question is all about jQuery?

Comment: The answer is no. Using a client base migration tool that just assists you upgrading (console.logging what you need to change) wil not update your server in any way

Comment: So not only do you need to update the jQuery, but also the bootstrap if it is used. I also suspect the localstorage.js. You might want to see if it contains code to handle browsers that did not support localstorage when the developer made the site

Comment: the treeselect might be [this 9 year old code](https://github.com/travist/jquery.treeselect.js), so you might want to find a newer one or rewrite the tree using code if you have one

Comment: Go here for bootstrap and make sure the jQuery tag is before the bootstrap one
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies.  M. Eriksson - I added the PHP tag since the site is written in PHP.

Comment: mplungjan - Thanks for the heads up on the migration, bootstrap, localstorage.js, and the treeselect.

Comment: just load the newest library and check what will fail :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I finished creating the test site and was able to load the latest library, nothing failed.  Loading jQuery 3.7.1 on the production site worked as well.  No jQuery migrations from 1.11.0 were needed.  Thanks again.